# Force partition to only mount in read only mode

Tags: dual-boot, mount, read-only

I have my laptop dual booted with Ubuntu 15.04, and I want to make sure that if I click on my Windows partition in nautilus it will only mount in read only mode, to protect my Windows 7 installation.

Is it possible?

If not, what alternatives are there that will protect my Windows 7 installation from modification when I am booted into Ubuntu?

Comment: I guess if you create an `/etc/fstab` entry for it and set the read-only flag, Nautilus should respect that... Look it up, the `man`pages are your friends - or google/duckduckgo/...